# why does this give a segmentation fault? it should just exit

Tags: linux, assembly

I am trying to learn low-level development.  By putting 0 in ebx and 1 in eax (for exit() syscall) and calling int 0x80, it should exit the program.
I have a simple c program that runs fine, but when I paste this in, instead of exiting as expected, I get a segmantation fault.  Why does this happen?

THANK YOU!

```
 __asm__ ("xor %ebx, %ebx;"
                 "mov %al, 1;"
                "int $80;"
);
```

edit: thanks for advice, still nothing but seg faults, though. 
here are modifications i've made:

```
  __asm__ ("xor %ebx, %ebx;"
           "xor %eax, %eax;"
                "mov $1, %eax;"
                "int $80;"
);
```

edit:  after modifying this example from http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html

```
asm("movl $1,%%eax;         /* SYS_exit is 1 */
             xorl %%ebx,%%ebx;      /* Argument is in ebx, it is 0 */
             int  $0x80"            /* Enter kernel mode */
             );
```

This finally worked for me:

```
asm("   movl $1,%eax;
        xorl %ebx,%ebx;
        int  $0x80
"
        );
```

thanks for looking and offering advice.

Comment: I don't know asm, but are `%al` and `eax` the same? Why is this tagged with "C"?

Comment: the c tag was there since this is being pasted into a c program as-is, and compiled with gcc.

Comment: Please try `int $0x80` instead of `int $80`. I'm pretty sure decimal notation is the default.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the rest of `eax` is cleared?  Try moving `1` into `eax` and not just `al` or at least clear it first.

```
__asm__ ("xor %ebx, %ebx;"
         "mov $1, %eax;"
         "int $0x80;"
);
```

**edit:** If AndiDog is right about AT&T syntax.

**edit:** It's been a while since I've used gas but 80<sub>16</sub> is `$0x80`.  `$80` is 80<sub>10</sub>.  This should fix the last of it.

Comment: This works for me (x86-64/Linux, compiled with -m32) except that it should be "mov $1, %eax" instead of "mov 1, %eax" -- the latter tries to read memory at address 00000001, which, of course, segfaults.  (And technically it should be "xorl" and "movl", but GAS seems to get it right regardless.)

Comment: @Zack: Ah yes, thanks for that.  I was just making tweaks on healy's code as an example and forgot about the syntax.  It's been a while...  :)

Comment: @Zack: Forgot to mention that `MOV` in GAS is a synthetic instruction AFAIK and will be converted to the appropriate move instruction in the assembler when necessary.  I know this applies on RISC architectures but wasn't aware it was necessary for x86 in particular.

Comment: I've spent a whole lot of time reading GCC assembly dumps but hardly any time writing assembly myself, so I didn't know that.  Thanks for the tidbit!

Answer (score 1):

This looks like AT&T assembler syntax, so operations are in the order "operation source, target" as opposed to "operation target, source" in the more common Intel syntax.

Knowing this, `mov %al, 1;` tries to write the content of the `al` register to the memory position 1. Change it to `mov 1, %al;` and it should work IMO. Note that I have never used AT&T syntax, so I'm not sure whether I interpreted it correctly.

**Edit:** And Jeff M is right, the syscall number must be stored in the `eax` register, so make sure it is cleared.